# Collections.sort(list, comparator) not reflecting the updated list when used with Jack and Java 1.8 on Android Studio

Tags: java, android, lambda, android-gradle-plugin, jack

**Person.java**

```
package com.example.android.cardview.HackerRank;

/**
* Created by Chhiring on 10/5/2017.
*/

public class Person {
   private String mFirstName;
   private String mLastNme;

   public Person() {
   }

   public Person(String mFirstName, String mLastNme) {
       this.mFirstName = mFirstName;
       this.mLastNme = mLastNme;
   }

   public String getmFirstName() {
       return mFirstName;
   }

   public void setmFirstName(String mFirstName) {
       this.mFirstName = mFirstName;
   }

   public String getmLastNme() {
       return mLastNme;
   }

   public void setmLastNme(String mLastNme) {
       this.mLastNme = mLastNme;
   }
}
```

**LambdaExpressionExample.java**

```
package com.example.android.cardview.HackerRank;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

/**
* Created by Chhiring on 10/9/2017.
*/
public class LambdaExpressionExample {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

       List<Person> myList = new ArrayList<>();

       myList.add(new Person("Chhiring", "Gurung"));
       myList.add(new Person("Jon", "Skeet"));
       myList.add(new Person("Joseph", "Rooney"));
       myList.add(new Person("Jack","Johnson"));

       System.out.println("Sort Based on first name");
       Collections.sort(myList, (o1, o2) -> o1.getmFirstName().compareTo(o2.getmFirstName()));
       for(Person p:myList){
           System.out.println(p.getmFirstName()+" "+p.getmLastNme());
       }

       System.out.println("\nSort Based on last name");
       Collections.sort(myList, (o1, o2) -> o1.getmLastNme().compareTo(o2.getmLastNme()));
       for(Person p:myList){
           System.out.println(p.getmFirstName()+" "+p.getmLastNme());
       }
   }
}
```

Whatever times, I put new Person in the list and run the `LambdaExpressionExample.java`, still it doesn’t give me the updated result. The code is 100% correct. I am using Android Studio. I have used Jack because I am using Java 1.8 for the lambda expression. Here is my `build.gradle` file

```
android {

defaultConfig /* is a com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ProductFlavor  */ {
   minSdkVersion 11
   targetSdkVersion 25

   jackOptions {
       enabled true
   }
}

compileOptions /* is a com.android.build.gradle.internal.CompileOptions */ {
   sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
   targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
}
```

But, when I do rebuild and run, I see the updated result. Why is this?

Comment: I'm not understanding the problem. What are you seeing and what were you expecting to see?

Comment: doing run doesn't update the list that i changed. it shows the previous values of list. After rebuilding and then running it updates list values. WHY?

Comment: I only see one set of inserts. What are the previous values and what are the updated values?

Comment: @Chhiring it might seem pedantic but even if it seems trivial you still need to include in your question the observed output and the expected... the latter is not as important as we can easily see what it would need to be based on the code but please include the former (the observed).

Comment: Lets assume I add new persons on the list and run the program, it still gives the old list values.

Comment: Also please add the Person class code.

Comment: you can see the Person.java class on the top @ValentinRuano

Comment: Oups! how I missed that :P

Comment: Its working fine @Chhiring **Chhiring Gurung**,
**Jack Johnson**,
**Jon Skeet**,
**Joseph Rooney** this is your Person Arraylist   after  sorting based on firstname **Chhiring Gurung**,
**Jack Johnson**,
**Joseph Rooney**,
**Jon Skeet**

Comment: You can check if the problem is with your code compiling/builiding system if you include a exception throw at the beginning of the code and is still producing some output.

Comment: @KalaiselvanA did you read my question properly. I never told that it is not  working but the scenario is different.

Comment: If you clean the project and rebuild you still have the issue?

Comment: Its works when we clean the project and rebuild. I want to know WHY?

Comment: Because probably the compilation was failing the the byte code had the old wrong compiled class with flawed logic?

Comment: That would not explain it if the rebuild was successful without further modifications... you may try to change it again and rebuild and see what happens... It would be down to a some misconfiguration of the project, a bug... Perhaps is you restart Studio you wont be able to reproduce it... I found that IDEs some times fail in mysterious ways an a restart or refresh to the latest version fixes the issue.